# Computing Higher Order Tensor of Variable Rank

Tags: function-construction, tensors, variable

The following code takes a vector `x` of variable length, computes the outer product of the vector with itself to form the matrix $\rho$ of dimension $2^n \times 2^n$. The function `T[i_, list_List]` then computes elements of a tensor $\mathcal{T}$ of rank $n$ according to

$$T_{\mu_1,...,\mu_n}=\text{Tr}(\rho \;\; \sigma_{\mu_1}\otimes...\otimes\sigma_{\mu_n})$$

with $\mu_1,...,\mu_n=1,2,3$ and $\sigma_i$ being the three Pauli Matrices.

```
OuterVectorProduct[x_] := KroneckerProduct[x, x]
```

```
T[i_, list_List] := 
 FullSimplify[Tr[i.KroneckerProduct @@ PauliMatrix[list]]]
```

That is: `T[rho,{1,1}]`outputs the $T_{11}$ element of the Tensor $\mathcal T$ with respect to some matrix $\rho$.

I would now like to write a function that outputs the entire tensor. To do so, I need to extract the number of arguments within the list in the function `T[i_,list_List]`.

That is, in our example `T[rho,{1,1}]`, I need to extract the number of arguments in the curly braces.

How does one do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient way to do so, but for descently sized `n`, this should work well:

```
T[i_, list_List] := Tr[i.KroneckerProduct @@ PauliMatrix[list]]
n = 4;
ρ = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2^n];
A = ArrayReshape[
   T[ρ, #] & /@ Tuples[Range[3], n], 
   ConstantArray[3, n]
   ];
A // Dimensions
```

> {3, 3, 3, 3}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I seem to get a $RecursionLimit error when running this code

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being dense here, but doesn't the fact that n is set to 4 define the length of the output string? Ideally, list_List should be an arbitary number of arguments, and the function returns the amount of arguments put into that list.

Comment: The size of the output should actually only depend on `ρ`. So, if you write a function of `ρ`, you would set `n = Log2[Length[ρ]]` in the body of that function.

Comment: Ah ok, gotcha. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!